# Не получается обновить значения в базе данных android

Tags: android, android-studio, sqlite, listview, update

Добрый день. Не получается выполнить апдейт записи в таблице БД. По клику выводится AlertDialog, в который мы вводим новое значение, которое затем должно обновиться в бд. Пытался сделать таким образом, но получаю:
**E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f7cd3bfa0**

```
public void editTask(View view){

            final EditText taskEdit = new EditText(this);
            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Редактирование заметки").setMessage("Введите новый текст заметки ")
                    .setView(taskEdit).setPositiveButton(" Изменить   ", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            String task = String.valueOf(taskEdit.getText());
                            SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                            ContentValues newvalues = new ContentValues();
                            newvalues.put(com.example.alexandrkuchinsky.myapplication.db.task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE,task);
                            String where = TaskEntry._ID + " = ?";

                            db.update(TaskEntry.TABLE, newvalues, where, null);

                            db.close();
                            updateUI();
                        }
                    })

                    .setNegativeButton("   Отмена   ", null).create();
            dialog.show();

    }
```

**класс TaskHelper**

```
 public class TaskHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

 public TaskHelper(Context context){
 super(context, task.DB_name, null, task.Db_versiom);

}
 @Override
 public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + task.TaskEntry.TABLE + " ( " +
                                    task.TaskEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY 
 KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                                    task.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE + " TEXT 
NOT NULL);";
db.execSQL(createTable);
  }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + task.TaskEntry.TABLE);
onCreate(db);
}


}
```

**Класс task**

```
public class task {

public static final String DB_name = "cas.example.com.todolist.db";
public static final int Db_versiom = 1;
public class TaskEntry implements BaseColumns{
public static final String TABLE = "tasks";
public static final String COL_TASK_TITLE = "title";

}
}
```

**метод updateUI**

```
    private void updateUI(){
 ArrayList<String> tasklist = new ArrayList<>();
 SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskEntry.TABLE, new String[]{TaskEntry._ID, 
 TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE}, null, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        tasklist.add(cursor.getString(index));

    }
if (mAdapter == null) {
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.item_todo, R.id.task_title, 
tasklist);
mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

} else{
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(tasklist);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
 }
```

Будьте добры: подскажите в чем я ошибся?

Comment: что за метод `updateUI()` (код) и на какой строке ошибка?

Comment: updateUI() прикрепил, ошибку не выдает. При клике выдает: E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f7cd3bfa0

Comment: похоже Вы попали на вот эту ошибку.. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37069061